# Find the closest value of each value in a column compared to another column in the same PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, closest

We have a PySpark dataframe containing rate codes that we have to use to give discounted offers to our customers.

[image]

-ratecode - Actual rate code
-weeklyrate - weekly dollar amount that the customer will pay
-area - area of residence
-frequency -
-offer1 - The first discounted offer to customer
-offer2 - The second discounted offer to customer

The problem is to find the closest "ratecode" corresponding to "offer1" (and save it as "offer1Ratecode") and "offer2" (saving as "offer2Ratecode").

Explanation:

1. for the "offer1" = 4.4 , the "offer1Ratecode" is R1, because the closest "weeklyrate" to 4.4 is 5.5 and 5.5 corresponds to "ratecode" R1
2. for the "offer1" = 6 , the "offer1Ratecode" is R2, because the closest "weeklyrate" to 6 is 6.2 and 6.2 corresponds to "ratecode" R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('R1', 5.5, 4.4, 3.85),
     ('R2', 6.2, 4.96, 4.34),
     ('R3', 7.5, 6.0, 5.25),
     ('R4', 5.6, 4.48, 3.92),
     ('R5', 7.3, 5.84, 5.11),
     ('R6', 8.4, 6.72, 5.88),
     ('R7', 9.1, 7.28, 6.37),
     ('R8', 6.8, 5.44, 4.76)],
    ['ratecode', 'weeklyrate', 'offer1', 'offer2'])
```

One way would be using `crossJoin` and `groupBy`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def closest(col):
    return F.array_sort(F.collect_list(F.struct(
        F.abs(F.col(f'b.{col}') - F.col('a.weeklyrate')).alias('diff'),
        'a.weeklyrate',
        'a.ratecode',
    )))[0]['ratecode'].alias(f'{col}Ratecode')

df = df.select('weeklyrate', 'ratecode').alias('a').crossJoin(df.alias('b'))
df = df.groupBy(*[f'b.{c}' for c in df.select('b.*').columns]).agg(
    closest('offer1'),
    closest('offer2'),
)
df.show()
# +--------+----------+------+------+--------------+--------------+
# |ratecode|weeklyrate|offer1|offer2|offer1Ratecode|offer2Ratecode|
# +--------+----------+------+------+--------------+--------------+
# |      R3|       7.5|   6.0|  5.25|            R2|            R1|
# |      R2|       6.2|  4.96|  4.34|            R1|            R1|
# |      R1|       5.5|   4.4|  3.85|            R1|            R1|
# |      R4|       5.6|  4.48|  3.92|            R1|            R1|
# |      R7|       9.1|  7.28|  6.37|            R5|            R2|
# |      R6|       8.4|  6.72|  5.88|            R8|            R4|
# |      R8|       6.8|  5.44|  4.76|            R1|            R1|
# |      R5|       7.3|  5.84|  5.11|            R4|            R1|
# +--------+----------+------+------+--------------+--------------+
```

Another could be using window functions and `transform`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

def closest(col):
    return F.array_sort(F.transform(
        F.collect_list(F.struct('weeklyrate', 'ratecode')).over(W.orderBy()),
        lambda x: F.struct(
            F.abs(F.col(col) - x['weeklyrate']).alias('diff'),
            x['weeklyrate'].alias('weeklyrate'),
            x['ratecode'].alias('ratecode'),
        )
    ))[0]['ratecode'].alias(f'{col}Ratecode')

df = df.select('*', closest('offer1'), closest('offer2'))
df.show()
# +--------+----------+------+------+--------------+--------------+
# |ratecode|weeklyrate|offer1|offer2|offer1Ratecode|offer2Ratecode|
# +--------+----------+------+------+--------------+--------------+
# |      R1|       5.5|   4.4|  3.85|            R1|            R1|
# |      R2|       6.2|  4.96|  4.34|            R1|            R1|
# |      R3|       7.5|   6.0|  5.25|            R2|            R1|
# |      R4|       5.6|  4.48|  3.92|            R1|            R1|
# |      R5|       7.3|  5.84|  5.11|            R4|            R1|
# |      R6|       8.4|  6.72|  5.88|            R8|            R4|
# |      R7|       9.1|  7.28|  6.37|            R5|            R2|
# |      R8|       6.8|  5.44|  4.76|            R1|            R1|
# +--------+----------+------+------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Hi ZygD, thanks a lot for this code snippet. It works like a beauty. Can't thank you enough. I must apologize for responding late as I am a new user and didn't realize that you have already posted an answer.

Comment: Hey,Wondering if you can help with yet another flavor of the same problem. I need to exclude certain rates from the original table while giving offers to the subscribers, Meaning these rate codes are not to be used in the offer1Ratecode and and offer2Ratecode columns. Can you help me tweak the windows function code to achieve this. e.g say we've another df named dfexclusion which contains R6 and R7. Expectation  is that when windows func version of code runs it excludes R6 and R7
dfexclusion = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('R6'),
              ('R7')],
             ['exclusionratecodes']

Comment: @sushapat - it would be better if you could post a separate question with example of input dataframes and expected output.